# How could one use an 'after' filter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know laravel has both `before` and `after` filters as options when processing routes.  I have been using the `before` filter check for authentication or memberships and returning other views or pages if conditions are not met.  I've read about other ways to use `before` filters but I have seen anyplace that describes why one would use an `after` filter.

Can anyone explain why such a filter is warranted and what some use cases could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be so many reasons to use an `after` filter to modify the response before sending it to the client, for example, this is a way to minimize the response by removing the comments and white spaces and it goes into the `after` filter:

```
if($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\Response)
{
    $filters = array(
        // Remove HTML comments except IE conditions
        '/<!--(?!\s*(?:\[if [^\]]+]|<!|>))(?:(?!-->).)*-->/s' => '',
        // Remove comments in the form /* */
        '/(?<!\S)\/\/\s*[^\r\n]*/' => '',
        // Shorten multiple white spaces
        '/>\s{2,}</' => '><',
        // Shorten multiple white spaces
        '/\s{2,}/' => ' ',
        // Collapse new lines
        '/(\r?\n)/' => '',
    );

    $output = $response->getOriginalContent();
    $output = preg_replace(array_keys($filters), array_values($filters), $output);
    $response->setContent($output);
}
```

Also, I use `WordPress` like `shortcode` in some views and dynamically replace the `shortcode` with a real `view` using following code, which goes in to `after` filter to modify the response:

```
$content = $response->getContent();
$pattern = '/\[filter_content:.*\]/';
if(!isAdmin() && preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches)) {
    $viewName = 'filtered_templates.' . substr($matches[0], (strpos($matches[0], ':') + 1), -1);
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, View::make($viewName), $content);
    return $response->setContent($output);
}
```

The `after` filter looks like:

```
 App::after(function($request, $response)
 {
     // You may modify the response before sending it to the client/browser
 });
```

You may use this (`after`) filter to set a custom `response header` as well, depending on the response you got from your controller.

Comment: Aside from modifying data before reaching the client, are there any other examples?  No need for code, just reasons :)

Comment: Did you see my last updated answer, I mentioned about response header.

Answer (score 1):

After filters receive the response to the request, so basically anything returned by your function.  This would allow you to make adjustments to it or modify it in someway before finally returning it to the client.

Comment: Hmm, that articulates the option better.  Can you give me an example of when you might want to do this?